# Convert a matrix of indices from a vector of values

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a vector containing values:

```
c = [52, 26, 17, 39, 43];
```

and a matrix containing the indices of the vector:

```
B = [1 5 3 2;
     4 2 3 1;
     2 4 3 1;
     4 4 1 2];
```

How do I convert B into a matrix B2 that contains the values in vector c given the indices in B?

```
B2 = [52 43 17 26;
      39 26 17 52;
      26 39 17 52;
      39 39 52 26];
```

A nested for loop achieves what I want:

```
for i = 1:4
 for j = 1:4
  B2(i,j) = c(B(i,j));
 end
end
```

However, this problem seems like it should be ripe for vectorization. Is there a way of doing this without for loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply index `c` with `B`:

```
B2 = c(B);
```

Comment: A better solution. +1. No need to reshape.